# How can I upload a blob as file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried upload a blob to firebase with below the code. But, I didn't succeed. Could you please help me.

My reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

function mUpload() {
var i_note = document.getElementById('note').value;

var mblob = new Blob([i_note], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

// var file = new File([mblob], "filename")
var file = new File([mblob], "filename", {type: 'text/plain', lastModified: Date.now()});

var metadata = {
'contentType': file.type
};

storageRef.child('Books/myfile.txt').put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {
var url = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
}).catch(function(error) {
console.error('Upload failed:', error);
});   
}
```

Very very thanks for helping..

Comment: The [reference for put](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) indicates that you can just pass a Blob as the first argument. Have you tried that?

Comment: I can confirm that passing a Blob to `put` works, I used that earlier in the week. If you're having problems with that, can you reproduce it in a jsbin?

Comment: I tried  but didn't work. I edited my question. Could you please look it again.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: No error, nothing happen. Also I tried new thing (convert blog to file). I edited my question again. Result is nothing again. Maybe creating and uploading operations are happen same time. Could this be a problem?